# Login based on user type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making a web application using asp.net mvc 3, which has login also.

There are 3 different types of users who will be using the site: Administrator, Operator & Distributor.

How can I create a login that restricts a Distributor from accessing Administrator's & Operator's part of the website. Similarly an Operator should not be able to access Administrator & Distributor part. Also Administrator should not be able to access other type of user's part. i.e. the site should redirect an Administrator type of user to his own part of website after login.

And finally no one should able to access their own part of website without login.

Please could anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [the membership model of ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx). This model is used to authenticate and authorize users for different parts of your web application.

With the membership model, define three roles within your application: Administrator, Operator and Distributor. Of course, also create users within your application and divide them over these roles.

Last up is the actual authentication and authorization. Use the [Authorize attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) to define which role a user must have to access a certain part of your website.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Operator")]
public ActionResult OperatorOnlyStuff()
{
    return View();
}
```

And to make sure users should be logged in to even access anything on your site, define a [custom authenticated route constraint](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx).

```
public class AuthenticatedRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

And use this custom authenticated route constraint in your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { isAuthenticated = new AuthenticatedConstraint()}
);
```

Comment: How do we use MySql as backend and not SQL Server.

Comment: The membership model works with providers that do the actual work of managing users and roles. Using MySQL is no problem, just use a MySQL membership provider. You can write this yourself, but you're not the only one with this wish, so you can also check out what others have already done: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/